# PHP different email submission id for different region

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I am using **html form** with **php mail** function embedded. I have 3 region in my form as a dropdown. If anybody selects the first region form submission should go to one mail id, if someone selects the second region it should go to different email id. So please tell me how to code it in PHP with  a single form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `array` for `region-email`s like -

```
$emails = array('first' => 'first@region.com', 'second' => 'second@region.com', 'third' => 'third@region.com');
```

Get the email like -

```
$email = $email[$_POST['region']];
```

Add the checks as you need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simply if else

```
$region = $_POST['region'];

if($region == "first")
mail();
else if($region == "second")
mail();
else if($region == "third")
mail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Elyor 's approach:

```
$region = $_POST['region'];
switch ($region) {
    case 'North':
        $email_address = 'northsales@acme.com';
        break;
    case 'South':
        $email_address = 'southsales@acme.com';
        break;
    case 'East':
       $email_address = 'eastsales@acme.com';
        break;
    default:
       $email_address = 'sales@acme.com';
}
mail($email_address, 'Sales enquiry', 'Please contact us with regards your product');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In HTML if you put email as value in option list like

<select name="region">
<option value="abc@gmail.com">region one</option>
<option value="abc1@gmail.com">region two</option>
<option value="abc2@gmail.com">region three</option>
</select>
```

then you can use directly

```
mail($_POST['region'], 'Sales enquiry', 'Please contact us with regards your product');
```

no need to do extra coding.